# hazelcast queue is not accesssible from listener

Tags: python, message-queue, hazelcast

I have a message queue called (train) and whenever anything added to it I want to create a new queue or perform some operations . So i have attached the listener  to the queue and from the listener I am starting new queue. But the problem is I could not start a queue from the listener as it throwing some error.

```
'''
This function will be called when we add anything to message_queue.
'''
def notify_when_added(event):
    res = event.item
    if res.status == Activity.train:
        print(res.text)
    elif res.status == Activity.predict:
        print('predict')
        queue = MessageQueue.create_msg_queue("predict") #error in this line



if __name__ == "__main__":
    #load_predictor()
    train_queue = MessageQueue.create_msg_queue("train")

    train_queue.add_listener(True, notify_when_added) #creating a listener
    res = Response(Activity.predict, "Model Trained with test accuracy of: ", "coles_auto_4", 5002)
    train_queue.add_all([res])
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

So basically here I am adding something to train_queue and want to create new queue which will be used by other processes. But I am getting the following error. This error occurs only when I use add_listener and try to create or access queue in listener. I want to start a queue from the listener which can be used by other process.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shiva_burade\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\hazelcast\cluster.py", line 124, in _connect_to_cluster
    self._connect_to_address(address)
  File "C:\Users\shiva_burade\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\hazelcast\cluster.py", line 171, in _connect_to_address
    connection = f.result()
  File "C:\Users\shiva_burade\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\hazelcast\future.py", line 58, in result
    self._reactor_check()
  File "C:\Users\shiva_burade\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\hazelcast\future.py", line 70, in _reactor_check
    "Synchronous result for incomplete operation must not be called from Reactor thread. "
RuntimeError: Synchronous result for incomplete operation must not be called from Reactor thread. Use add_done_callback instead.
Aug 27, 2019 05:41:19 PM HazelcastClient.ClusterService
WARNING: [3.12.1] [dev] [hz.client_1] Unable to get alive cluster connection, attempt 2 of 2
Aug 27, 2019 05:41:19 PM HazelcastClient.InvocationService
WARNING: [3.12.1] [dev] [hz.client_0] Error handling event ClientMessage:{length=327, correlationId=6, messageType=204, partitionId=216, isComplete=True, isRetryable=False, isEvent=True, writeOffset=22}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shiva_burade\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\hazelcast\invocation.py", line 293, in _handle_event
    invocation.event_handler(message)
  File "C:\Users\shiva_burade\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\hazelcast\proxy\queue.py", line 91, in <lambda>
    lambda m: queue_add_listener_codec.handle(m, handle_event_item),
  File "C:\Users\shiva_burade\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\hazelcast\protocol\codec\queue_add_listener_codec.py", line 48, in handle
    handle_event_item(item=item, uuid=uuid, event_type=event_type)
  File "C:\Users\shiva_burade\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\hazelcast\proxy\queue.py", line 85, in handle_event_item
    item_added_func(item_event)
    File "controller_flask.py", line 33, in notify_when_added
queue = MessageQueue.create_msg_queue("predict")
  File "D:\text category\message_queue.py", line 56, in create_msg_queue
    client = hazelcast.HazelcastClient(config)
  File "C:\Users\shiva_burade\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\hazelcast\client.py", line 59, in __init__
    self._start()
  File "C:\Users\shiva_burade\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\hazelcast\client.py", line 64, in _start
    self.cluster.start()
  File "C:\Users\shiva_burade\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\hazelcast\cluster.py", line 50, in start
    self._connect_to_cluster()
  File "C:\Users\shiva_burade\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\hazelcast\cluster.py", line 142, in _connect_to_cluster
    raise HazelcastError(error_msg)
hazelcast.exception.HazelcastError: Could not connect to any of {Address(host=127.0.0.1, port=5701)} after 2 tries
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not answer the question fully but I also got the following error when I wanted to get/subscribe/unsubscribe from a topic inside a callback function called when a message is received from another topic.

> Synchronous result for incomplete operation must not be called from
> Reactor thread. Use add_done_callback instead.

Apparently, some operations that implies the Hazelcast client cannot be performed inside the callback function (the "Reactor" thread). As I could not add the add_done_callback on any of these operations, I eventually set a variable inside the callback function and check the status of this variable in the main (e.g. in a loop).
That's certainly not the most handy/efficient way but at least there is a workaround...